# Accessing data attribute in text of newly created div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am appending a new div to a list on the click of a button, and I would like the text of my new div to contain a data attribute.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var balance = 0.00;
    var playerCount = 0;
    var avgBalance = 0.00;
    $("#server-balance").html("Server balance: $" + balance);
    $("#player-count").html("Players online: " + playerCount);
    $("#average-balance").html("Average player balance: $" + avgBalance);

    function handleEntryButtonClick() {

        playerCount++;
        balance = balance + 0.10;
        avgBalance = balance / playerCount;

        var balAdjust = balance.toFixed(2);
        var avgAdjust = avgBalance.toFixed(2);

        $("#server-balance").html("Server balance: $" + balAdjust);
        $("#player-count").html("Players online: " + playerCount);
        $("#average-balance").html("Average player balance: $" + avgAdjust);

        $("<div/>", {
            "class": "player-label",
            "data-player-balance": 10, 
            text: "Player " + playerCount + " balance: " + $(this).attr("data-player-balance")
        }).appendTo("#player-label-lst");

    }

    $("#entry-btn").on("click", handleEntryButtonClick);
});
```

I keep generating a new div with the text "Player X balance: undefined".
How can I solve this issue?

Comment: can you add all relevant especially the button that calls the click

Comment: I have edited my post to include my entire .js file

Comment: add also the HTML mark up since you are getting the attribute of the button

Comment: $(this) referring button not div element. Also you already know that "data-player-balance" is 10 then why you need it read from attribute?

Answer (score 0):

It is because at the moment you create the div, it does not have the attribute "data-player-balance" yet. You may try to store it in a variable first, and then use it in both attributes.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    var balance = 0.00;
    var playerCount = 0;
    var avgBalance = 0.00;
    $("#server-balance").html("Server balance: $" + balance);
    $("#player-count").html("Players online: " + playerCount);
    $("#average-balance").html("Average player balance: $" + avgBalance);

    function handleEntryButtonClick() {

        playerCount++;
        balance = balance + 0.10;
        avgBalance = balance / playerCount;

        var balAdjust = balance.toFixed(2);
        var avgAdjust = avgBalance.toFixed(2);

        $("#server-balance").html("Server balance: $" + balAdjust);
        $("#player-count").html("Players online: " + playerCount);
        $("#average-balance").html("Average player balance: $" + avgAdjust);
        
        const playerBalance = 10;

        $("<div/>", {
            "class": "player-label",
            "data-player-balance": playerBalance, 
            text: "Player " + playerCount + " balance: " + playerBalance
        }).appendTo("#player-label-lst");

    }

    $("#entry-btn").on("click", handleEntryButtonClick);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="server-balance"></div>
<div id="player-count"></div>
<div id="average-balance"></div>

<div id="player-label-lst"></div>
<button id="entry-btn">Entry</button>
```